# Arguments And Lists in Haskell

Tags: list, haskell, arguments

I'm super bloody new to Haskell. Coming from other languages like Java or C I have some problems understanding how functions in Haskell use arguments. I understand the concept of polymorphism, how Haskell uses types and how everything seems to be a tree but I have a hard time applying these concepts to the syntax.

Let's say I want to program a function that takes a string-list and just adds "1" and "2" to it.

```hs
addOneTwo :: [String] -> [String]
addOneTwo [] = "1" : "2" : [x]
```

I understand that this question might have been answered elsewhere but I have not yet seen an answer that explains it in a way so that I as a total newbi can understand.

Comment: What exactly *is* your question?

Comment: `f [] = ...` means "if the input list is empty then the result is ...". Usually it's followed by another equation covering the non-empty case. I don't know why you use that in your code. Try instead `f xs = "1" : "2" : xs` -- no need to distinguish between the empty/nonempty cases here.

Answer (score 2):

```
addOneTwo :: [String] -> [String]
addOneTwo [] = "1" : "2" : [x]
```

This says:

- `addOneTwo` is a function that accepts a `[String]` and returns a `[String]`
- When `addOneTwo` is called on an empty list, that is, `addOneTwo []`, it evaluates to a list where:

  - The head is `"1"`
  - The tail is a list where:

    - The head is `"2"`
    - The tail is a list of one element, `x` (or, in other words, its head is `x` and its tail is `[]`)

Since you don’t define a variable called `x` in this code, this is a scoping error. One way to fix this is the following:

- Remove the pattern `[]` and replace it with the pattern `x`, that is, just a parameter name.
- Since this parameter is a list, use it as the second operand of the cons operator `(:)` directly, that is, `… : x` instead of *`… : [x]`

```
addOneTwo :: [String] -> [String]
addOneTwo x = "1" : "2" : x
```

Conventionally, lists are often named with an `s` suffix, like `xs` or `strings`, so you could rename `x` too if you like.

To understand your original code in more depth, maybe it’ll be illuminating to go over how it would be desugared:

```
addOneTwo =
  \ xs -> case xs of {
    [] -> "1" : ("2" : (x : []));
    _ -> error "Non-exhaustive patterns in function addOneTwo"
  }
```

Since `addOneTwo` is a function, it can be defined using a function *value*, that is, a lambda expression. I’ve given the parameter of this function the name of `xs`. When you write the definition `addOneTwo [] = …`, the *pattern* `addOneTwo []` means you’re defining the result of evaluating the *expression* `addOneTwo []`. The “equals” sign really does mean “equals”!

This is equivalent to taking a parameter and pattern-matching on it explicitly with a `case` expression. Notice that I included an `error` case, which is implicitly generated when you don’t cover all possible inputs—in this case, when `addOneTwo` is applied to a non-empty list, like `addOneTwo [3]`. GHC can warn you about such uncovered cases if you enable `-Wincomplete-patterns`; that’s implied by `-Wall`, which produces a variety of other helpful warnings.

Whereas, the corrected definition would desugar to the following:

```
addOneTwo =
  \ x ->
    "1" : ("2" : x)
```

Since all inputs will be matched by the pattern `x`, there is no need for an `error` alternative, or any `case` expression at all.

> I want to program a function that takes a string-list and just adds "1" and "2" to it.

Well, there you go! But keep in mind: this isn’t adding elements to the *same* list in-place, it’s just making a list that shares some suffix with the old one. And that’s the normal way of representing incremental updates to a data structure in Haskell: a function `f :: T -> T` takes in a value representing one state and returns a value representing the modified state, and we rely on the garbage collector to reclaim parts of the old state that are no longer used.